# Realm database execute

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm

when I want to execute realm database I got this error, how can I solve this error , Running transactions on the UI thread has been disabled. It can be enabled by setting
'RealmConfiguration.Builder.allowWritesOnUiThread(true)'

Comment: Running transactions on the UI thread is not something you should consider doing at all.

Comment: thanks for answering my problem.to fix that what should i do?

Comment: Execute the transaction in background thread. Realm already has a function: `executeTransactionAsync` .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Realm.init(getApplicationContext());

//Use this code after Realm.init(context)
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .allowWritesOnUiThread(true)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();
        realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
```